# multiple instances of spring cloud kafka binder to write to single file

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a requirement where I need to read message from a kafka topic in springboot application, extract few attributes from the message and create a file with extracted values, this is easy to implement if I have a single consumer.

But in my case I will have multiple instances of consumers will be running based on load in k8s, in a consumer-group. In this case how can I make sure all consumers write to same file without overriding the data from each other? Number of messages can go upto 500k.

I avoided persisting to DB and then use another process to read from DB and create file. Is there better way of doing this without DB or shared cache ?

Comment: What do you mean by "shared cache"? What it would be wrong? Also, what did you tried yet?

Comment: shared cache I meant distributed cache, which needs clean up and all after usage of data. And I tried using DB approach.

Comment: You can try Hadoop File System API or the Amazon S3 SDK to write to the file in a thread-safe manner. The API or SDK will handle the concurrent writes and ensure that all the data is written correctly.

But, I would suggest using a distributed stream processing framework like Apache Kafka Streams or Apache Flink to process the messages in parallel.

Comment: I was thinking about making one thread that were making the job for all others, so it will be the distributed cache as you mean ?

Comment: Making a single thread inside a spring kafka consumer? What will happen if I spin-off multiple instances of this application, it will still create one file/instance right? In my case multiple instance should create one file

Answer (score 0):

Any written files would only be local to the machine where your consumers run, regardless of how/what framework consumed them.

You need some external process to then copy those files to a central location, such as file server, cache, database, anything. That's not something Kafka API is responsible for.

You could use Kafka Connect instead of writing any consumer code, by the way

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention in the question where the file will be created. The file will be created in S3 bucket, but I would like to create the file once all messages are consumed by all consumers in a group, till a given offset

Comment: There is no easy way for Kafka to know "all messages" are consumed. You can check `consumerLag == 0`, but if you have a very active Producer, and a slow consumer (which probably will be, if flushing data to files/S3, periodically), then you may never reach zero lag. Like I said, S3 Sink Connector can already write files, and extract data from records, and create unique files per topic+partition. So, maybe start with that?

Comment: But in mycase I don't need file per partition, I need one file for all partition

Comment: That's not really possible without one consumer (meaning very high lag) or with only one topic partition. In other words, you would need to open multiple file handles, and so multiple writers would conflict with what offset/line of that file they are writing. Even if you have two process on one machine writing to one file, not S3, then you will run into errors.